# Chloro functional group is given number 4 in phenol but number 1 in nitrobenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

In the IUPAC name 4-chlorophenol, we see that, the C atom where OH group is attached, is given number 1. But in the IUPAC name 1-chloro-4-nitrobenzene, we see that, the C atom where $NO_2$ group is attached, is given number 4. In the first case, phenol is the base. So C atom of OH group of the base is given number 1. Applying the same rule to the second case, C atom of the $NO_2$ group should be given number 1. Please help to clarify this point. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: "Applying the same rule to the second case" – which rule? Note that the parent structure of the second example is benzene and not nitrobenzene.

Comment: @Loong, in that case, the parent structure of the first example must also be benzene. We can not consider phenol as the parent structure. I must be missing some thing.

Comment: Why does it have to be benzene/phenol? In a way, the same 'rule' applies to 3-chloropropan-1-ol, for example. The alcohol gets the low locant.

Comment: @orthocresol Then NO2 must get the low locant in the second example in my question.

Comment: There is no rule that Cl must be the last.

Comment: Why should NO2 get the low locant? It's a plain old substituent prefix, just like chloro. If it was a bromo instead of a nitro, it would go first, because of alphabetical order. Alcohols, on the other hand, are generally *suffixes*, which tend to get priority over other prefixed substituents.